# jquery getting the data of form DIV to PHP $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have this working JQuery that let the user choose a color and changes the image + the name of the color that he/she have chosen. what i want is to get the value of **the name of the color** to `PHP $_POST`. i used data-caption to be able to change the name of the color.

this is the div that i want to get and this is the placeholder for changing the name.

```
<div id="caption">Alumina Jade Metallic</div>
```

this is the rest of the html code.

```
                    <span data-src="car-color/car_AJM.jpg" data-caption="Alumina Jade Metallic"><a href="#?" class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-Alumina-Jade.png">  </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="car-color/car_B.jpg" data-caption="Black Metallic"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Black.png"> </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="car-color/car_BRM.jpg" data-caption="Blackish Red Metallic"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Black-Red.png"> </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="car-color/car_BMM.jpg" data-caption="Blue Metallic"><a href="#?"class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-Blue-Metal.png"></a></span>
                    <span  data-src="car-color/car_FW.jpg" data-caption="Freedom White"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Freedom-White.png"> </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="car-color/car_OM.jpg" data-caption="Orange Metallic"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Orange-Metal.png"> </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="car-color/car_RMM.jpg" data-caption="Red Metallic"><a href="#?"class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-Red-Metal.png">  </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="car-color/car_SM.jpg" data-caption="Silver Metallic"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Silver-Metal.png">  </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="car-color/car_WP.jpg" data-caption="White Pearl"><a href="#?"class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-White-Pearl.png"> </a></span>
```

and this is my working jQuery :

```
$('.thumb span').each(function(){
  var _this = $(this);
  var src = _this.data("src");
  var text = _this.data("caption");
  _this.find('a').click(function(){
     $("#image").show( function() {
    $(".img img").attr("src", src);
    $("#caption").text(text);
     });
 });
});
```

**UPDATE**
this is my ajax code to pass it to my `request.php`

```
$('.car-quote #getQuote').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var variantOpt = $('#variantOpt').val();
            var fName = $('#fName').val();
            var lName = $('#lName').val();
            var address = $('#address').val();
            var doBirth = $('#doBirth').val();
            var city = $('#city').val();
            var zipCode = $('#zipCode').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var phone = $('#phone').val();
            var remarks = $('#remarks').val();
            var form = new Array({ 'variantOpt':variantOpt, 'fName':fName, 'lName':lName, 'address':address, 'doBirth':doBirth, 'city':city, 'zipCode':zipCode,
                                 'email':email, 'phone':phone, 'remarks':remarks });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/093017/inquiry/mailInqueries/requestaquote.php",
                data: ({'action': 'car-quote', 'form': form})
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#car-quote .result').html(data);

            $(".car-quote")[0].reset();
            });
```

and this is how it looks like when the form is passed in my `request.php`

```
$action = $_POST['action'];

    $variantOpt = $_POST['form'][0]['variantOpt'];
    $fName = $_POST['form'][0]['fName'];
    $lName = $_POST['form'][0]['lName'];
    $address = $_POST['form'][0]['address'];
    $doBirth = $_POST['form'][0]['doBirth'];
    $city = $_POST['form'][0]['city'];
    $zipCode = $_POST['form'][0]['zipCode'];
    $email = $_POST['form'][0]['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['form'][0]['phone'];
    $remarks = $_POST['form'][0]['remarks'];
```

Comment: Do you have the $_POST and the javascript in the same page?

Comment: i use a separate php for that but i do have the form on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch the contents of the div by using [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
var color = $('#caption').html();
```

Comment: forgot to tell you . i have an ajax for my form. and pass it to my php for sending mail.

Comment: Then, Could you please explain the issue? Everything looks to be in place.

Comment: passing the color name is not working because it's inside a div. cant get the value of it. i'll add the ajax and the php form.

Comment: I think i understand your issue now, Changed the answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: hello sorry for late reply. where will i put that ? and how do i get it to $_POST . ill try this and update you.

Comment: You can put it in your Ajax code where you request to request.php

`var doBirth = $(&#39;#doBirth&#39;).val(); var city = $(&#39;#city&#39;).val(); var zipCode = $(&#39;#zipCode&#39;).val();`

Moreover, you can fix the show() by adding a number(time in ms) as first parameter and then the callback function.

Comment: WOWW! IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM!. THANK YOU. that one line saved my life haha

Comment: Glad I could help.. Happy Coding!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157607/discussion-between-abhilash-nayak-and-jmv).